# Outlook 2016 Taking 30 to 60 Seconds to Open 1st Attachment

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've got a remote end user who experiences an issue where the first attachment he/she opens, no matter the file extension, will take a whole 30 to 60 seconds to load and open, while each subsequent attachment opens instantly. If it were an issue with pulling the file down from the server, it'd be doing this every time, but it's not, so I'm thinking that's not the case. This issue happens regardless of whether the email was already cached locally or not.

Anyone got any ideas aside from trying to get the user in and reinstalling Office?

Comment: It sounds like it's taking awhile the first time because you have to wait for the corresponding application (Word, Excel, etc.) to load first. And then subsequent attachments open quicker because the Office application itself is already loaded so the attachment opens almost instantly. Does that sound like what could be going on in your situation?

Comment: It's any attachment. Doesn't matter what program. If the file being waited on is a PDF, once that PDF loads, an Excel file will load instantly if that's the next attachment you open. It specifically happens any time when Outlook has just been opened, whether it's right after boot up or if you had just closed Outlook and then went to open Outlook again.

Comment: Yeah, a 3rd party program will not work for this end user. We don't want to buy software for something that shouldn't be having issues as it is, and the attachment is already in the local Exchange Cache for the user anyway and it still has this problem.


That and the user probably wouldn't be open to using 3rd party software that completely changes how they interact with email.

Other people in our team are now pretty sure it's an issue with Skylake processors anyway.